# Martiglale and Brownian Motion

Tags: brownian-motion

Stock market has been model as a random walk with a drift.  Since it has a drift(bigger than zero) it is not a "Brownian Motion" but it still a Martingale?
Is Stock market a Brownian Motion?
Is it a Martingale?

Comment: You could say it's an exponential martingale.

Comment: A lot of people assume stock prices are a geometric Brownian motion, which is not a martingale. It should be noted that although some stock prices look like a geometric Brownian motion there is an enormous amount of evidence to suggest they are not.

Comment: The question is invalid because the stock is NOT a martingale under the real-world measure.

Answer (score 1):

The stock market is modeled as a brownian motian,with a real world drift usually  larger than zero. This sort of model would be similiar to the CAPM or APT , VaR.
The martingale  is a mathematical  condition  that assure  no arbitrage used in derivatives  pricing, black scholes style. In that case the drift usually  is the risk free rate of such economy.

Comment: This is one of the simplest models, but yes, it makes the difference clear.

Answer (score 1):

In real world probabilities it is not a martingale as the expected value of the stock in the future will be different than its actual value, because of its non-zero drift.

In the risk-neutral probability world the stock price discounted by the risk-free rate can be considered as a martingale.